# Change Array Formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How to change this Javascript array format:

```
var sample_data = ["af","16.63","al","11.58","dz","158.97"];
```

to this object format:

```
var sample_data = {"af":"16.63","al":"11.58","dz":"158.97"};
```

Comment: What is the language? If it is JavaScript, you have syntactical error in the first snippet. It must be `var sample_data = ["af","16.63","al","11.58","dz","158.97"];`

Comment: Language??? Add the language/technology tags.

Comment: i changed the bracket type to []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var d = {}; // a temporary object
for (var i = 0; i < sample_data.length; i += 2) {
    // iterate over sample_data with a step width of 2
    // and set the the data in the temp. object
    d[sample_data[i]] = sample_data[i+1];
}
sample_data = d;
```

Answer (score 2):

Could use Array.shift to do it too. No idea how it compares to other methods speed wise.

```
var sample_data = ["af","16.63","al","11.58","dz","158.97"]; // source

var data = sample_data.slice(); // clone the data

sample_data = {};

while (data.length > 1) {
    sample_data[data.shift()] = data.shift() || null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the code for it will look like this

```
var sample_data = ["af","16.63","al","11.58","dz","158.97"];
var tmp = sample_data;
sample_data = {};
for (var i = 0; i < tmp.length / 2; i++) 
    sample_data[tmp[i * 2]] = tmp[i * 2 + 1];
```

**EDIT**

Keep in mind.

```
var arr = []; // This is an array
var obj = {}; // This is an object! Not array.
```